# struts 2 and jasper reports integration

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

I want to integrate jasper report to my struts 2 application.

But I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:325)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
interceptor.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:40)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

**jars I have added:**

struts 2 core 2.3.15  
jasper reports 3.1.2 
commons lang 3.2 
commons digester 1.7 
commons beanutils 1.7.0 
commons collections 2.1 
common logging 1.0 
struts2 jasper report plugin 2.3.15 
joda time 2.1.0

Here is **report file**.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
          pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555"
          leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20"
          name="our_jasper_template">



<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0" />
<property name="ireport.x" value="0" />
<property name="ireport.y" value="0" />

<field name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" >

    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="552"
                           height="35" backcolor="#CCCCCC"  />
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="26" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[user Report]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20">

        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="15">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[Page:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Action class**

```
public class TestJasperAction extends ActionSupport {

 List<PolicyBean> beanCollection=new ArrayList();
@Override
public String execute() {
     ResultSet rs = PolicyDao.getPolicyRsTest();
     try {
         while (rs.next()) {
             PolicyBean p = new PolicyBean();
             p.setCustomerName(rs.getString("customer_first_name") + " " + rs.getString("customer_last_name"));

             p.setCustomerId(rs.getString("customer_no"));

             beanCollection.add(p);
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(TestJasperAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     System.out.println("Bean size:"+beanCollection.size());


    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<PolicyBean> getBeanCollection() {
    return beanCollection;
}

public void setBeanCollection(List<PolicyBean> beanCollection) {
    this.beanCollection = beanCollection;
}

}
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <action name="JasperTesting" class="action.TestJasperAction">
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
        <param name="location">/iacms/jaspers/our_jasper_template.jasper</param>
        <param name="dataSource">beanCollection</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
    </result>
```

**JSP code:**

```
 <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 250px">
      <s:form action="JasperTesting">
           <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-success" value="Generate Report"/>
     </s:form>
</div>
```

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using a very old version of Jasper Reports, my guess is that the jrxml is developed/compiled with 1 version and you are using another version in struts, for example in old version you need to set `printOrder` in jrxml tag so that the filler could be instanced.